# Why do loads in a circuit limit current?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, short-circuits

I found this quote on sparkfun.com and I'm confused.

"If you DO have a load in the current, the current flow through your circuit will be limited to that which your device consumes, which is usually a very small amount."

So if I had an LED, will the current from the battery be only strong enough to power the LED?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found this quote on sparkfun.com and I'm confused.

I understand why; the quote is confusing.  Do you have a link to the quote?

First, what is a load?  A *load*, in this context, is that which electric power is delivered (contrast with a *source* which, generally, supplies power).

A load can be characterized by its [I-V (current-voltage) curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current%E2%80%93voltage_characteristic) which essentially tells you the current through for a given voltage across.

So, *if the voltage across the load is fixed* by, e.g., a voltage source, the current delivered by the source is determined by the load.

> So if I had an LED, will the current from the battery be only strong
>   enough to power the LED?

Consider the I-V curve of some typical LEDs:

[image]

[Image credit](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_8.html)

Note that the LED current *strongly* depends on the voltage across; the LED current can change by a large amount for a small change in source voltage.

For this reason, a resistor is typically placed in series with the LED which will greatly reduce the dependence of the LED current with source voltage.

To find the operating current, a [load-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_line_(electronics)) is helpful

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By analagy to water.
The load is the "hole in the dam" through which the electrons flow. For a given voltage (dam height) the size of the load (size of hole) defines the current.
If too much current is drawn by a load the PSU will fail to maintain the voltage (the level of water behind the dam will drop).